# op_Subtraction method in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Can anyone help me with below code of PowerShell :

Please let me know if this is not the right platform for this question.

I am trying to get the unused space by subtracting total and free space and facing below error.

Also can I get help on how to get the free space percentage.

```
$srv=$env:COMPUTERNAME
$frspace=Get-WmiObject win32_volume -ComputerName $srv | Select @{N='FreeSpace';e={[Int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}}
$totSpace=Get-WmiObject win32_volume -ComputerName $srv | Select @{N='capacity';e={[Int]($_.capacity/1GB)}} 
$unused=$totSpace-$frspace
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
$srv=$env:COMPUTERNAME

Get-WmiObject win32_volume -ComputerName $srv | select Name, @{N='FreeSpace';e={[Int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}}, @{N='capacity';e={[Int]($_.capacity/1GB)}}, @{n="FreeSpace%"; e={"{0:N2}" -f (100*$_.FreeSpace / $_.capacity)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Gareth.